# jade output issue : different result on index.js and pm2

Tags: node.js, pug, pm2

I have a problem on jade project.

When I deploy the following code with node *index.js* the output is proper. But when I deploy it with *pm2* output html is different and hence no proper display.

```
include template/header.jade
  .content-wrapper
    h3.page-heading.mb-4 Dashboard
    .row
      .col-xl-3.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.mb-4
        .card.card-statistics
          .card-body
            .clearfix
              .float-left
                h4.text-danger
                  i.fa.fa-bar-chart-o.highlight-icon(aria-hidden='true')
              .float-right
                p.card-text.text-dark Visitors
                h4.bold-text 65,650
            p.text-muted
              i.fa.fa-exclamation-circle.mr-1(aria-hidden='true')
              |  65% lower growth
      .col-xl-3.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.mb-4
        .card.card-statistics
          .card-body
            .clearfix
              .float-left
                h4.text-warning
                  i.fa.fa-shopping-cart.highlight-icon(aria-hidden='true')
              .float-right
                p.card-text.text-dark Orders
                h4.bold-text 656
            p.text-muted
              i.fa.fa-bookmark-o.mr-1(aria-hidden='true')
              |  Product-wise sales
      .col-xl-3.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.mb-4
        .card.card-statistics
          .card-body
            .clearfix
              .float-left
                h4.text-success
                  i.fa.fa-dollar.highlight-icon(aria-hidden='true')
              .float-right
                p.card-text.text-dark Revenue
                h4.bold-text $65656
            p.text-muted
              i.fa.fa-calendar.mr-1(aria-hidden='true')
              |  Weekly Sales
      .col-xl-3.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.mb-4
        .card.card-statistics
          .card-body
            .clearfix
              .float-left
                h4.text-primary
                  i.fa.fa-twitter.highlight-icon(aria-hidden='true')
              .float-right
                p.card-text.text-dark Followers
                h4.bold-text +62,500
            p.text-muted
              i.fa.fa-repeat.mr-1(aria-hidden='true')
              |  Just Updated
    .row
      .col-md-5.mb-4
        .card
          .card-body
            h5.card-title Orders
            .row
              .col-12
                .mb-4
                  p.card-text.text-muted.mb-2 Pending orders
                  .progress.progress-slim
                    .progress-bar.bg-primary(role='progressbar', style='width: 25%', aria-valuenow='25', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                .mb-4
                  p.card-text.text-muted.mb-2 Shipped orders
                  .progress.progress-slim
                    .progress-bar.bg-success(role='progressbar', style='width: 55%', aria-valuenow='55', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                .mb-4
                  p.card-text.text-muted.mb-2 Returned orders
                  .progress.progress-slim
                    .progress-bar.bg-warning(role='progressbar', style='width: 35%', aria-valuenow='35', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                .mb-4
                  p.card-text.text-muted.mb-2 Cancelled orders
                  .progress.progress-slim
                    .progress-bar.bg-danger(role='progressbar', style='width: 85%', aria-valuenow='85', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                .mb-4
                  p.card-text.text-muted.mb-2 Cancelled orders
                  .progress.progress-slim
                    .progress-bar.bg-info(role='progressbar', style='width: 85%', aria-valuenow='85', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
              .col-12
                p.text-muted.mb-0
                  | Note: Order details get updated every 10 minutes
      .col-md-4.mb-4
        .card
          .card-body
            h5.card-title Total Sales
            .custom-legend-container.w-75.mx-auto
              canvas#sales-chart
            #sales-chart-legend.legend-right
      .col-md-3.mb-4
        .card
          .card-body
            h5.card-title Sales region
            .table-responsive.table-sales
              table.table
                thead
                  tr
                    th(colspan='2')
                      | Country
                    th.text-right
                      | Sales
                tbody
                  tr
                    td
                      .flag
                        i.flag-icon.flag-icon-us
                    td USA
                    td.text-right
                      | 2.920

                  tr
                    td
                      .flag
                        i.flag-icon.flag-icon-ro
                    td Romania
                    td.text-right
                      | 600
                  tr
                    td
                      .flag
                        i.flag-icon.flag-icon-br
                    td Brasil
                    td.text-right
                      | 550
    .card-deck
      .card.col-lg-12.px-0.mb-4
        .card-body
          h5.card-title Last Billings
          .table-responsive
            table.table.center-aligned-table
              thead
                tr.text-primary
                  th Order No
                  th Product Name
                  th Purchased On
                  th Shipping Status
                  th Payment Method
                  th Payment Status
                  th
                  th
                  th
              tbody
                tr
                  td 034
                  td Iphone 7
                  td 12 May 2017
                  td Dispatched
                  td Credit card
                  td
                    label.badge.badge-success Approved
                  td
                    a.btn.btn-outline-success.btn-sm(href='#') View Order
                  td
                    a.btn.btn-outline-warning.btn-sm(href='#') Cancel

                tr
                  td 038
                  td Mac Mini
                  td 19 May 2017
                  td Dispatched
                  td Debit card
                  td
                    label.badge.badge-success Approved
                  td
                    a.btn.btn-outline-success.btn-sm(href='#') View Order
                  td
                    a.btn.btn-outline-warning.btn-sm(href='#') Cancel
include template/footer.jade
```

[image]
[image]

How can I manage this with includes?

All the help is appreciated.
I have tried with many indents and outdents. but nothing works well.

Comment: Why the `.content-wrapper`(second line) have an indent? Is it supposed to be a child of `include template/header.jade`? I don't think it should.

Comment: i just tried @Gibin. Even more space is added on top. should i share more detail?

Comment: Yes, if possible please share the css as well. I use this ['site'](http://html2jade.org) for converting, please let me know whether it produces the expected result for you.

Comment: Here is code for header

    https://codepen.io/alithestar2000/pen/QQKPjE

Here is code for footer

https://codepen.io/alithestar2000/pen/vdXMGM.

the code in the middle i already shared

Comment: @GibinEalias I also use initially html to jade site. you know it's developer's need to create header footer files in order to keep common tasks once. after i use include statement it does some problems. my 2nd pen also includes my css

Comment: perhaps it was not saved. in css portion now you can find my css

Comment: Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/xYEezm).
Is this what the expected output is?

Comment: yes output is great except for the 2nd menu item which is moved to left more.

Comment: i need to keep header and footer in separate files. this is necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164677/discussion-between-gibin-ealias-and-qasim-ali).

Comment: Awaiting your reply in the chat.

Comment: @Gibin Ealias sorry for the delayed response. 2ndly thanks for your greatness in terms of helping and caring attitude. last day we decided to go with some other template engine. we decided blade would work. Since I am a php developer basically and just started nodejs. I know blade templating already. we will manage the things with that. 

in future if i ever need help, i would connect with you.

since it is the start of the project and only 3 or 4 pages been developed so it won't be difficult to switch.

Thank you so much. everything from you is appreciated